# How to calculate average time difference in 2 columns in the given table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has 3 columns, customer_id, datetime1, datetime2.

How to calculate the average of the time difference between these to datetime columns? If 2nd date time values is missing, it should not be considered for the calculation. I have to add the time difference from the rows which do not have missing values and take the average.

[image]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thank you, updated it to posgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the difference and average:

```
select avg(datetime2 - datetime1)
from t;
```

`avg()` ignores `NULL` values.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=44824e0bb83772552a99fd0587b3b06c) is a db<>fiddle.